# How to optimize sitecore queries?

Tags: optimization, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Hi I know most probably this query was asked. How can I improve query performance on Sitecore queries. I've installed dotTrancer and got the results you can see into [this](http://prntscr.com/8zqwtm) image. My method with I did not displayed in the image tooked 2,551 ms and Sitecore query toked 2,344 ms which is huge.
I am using Sitecore 7.2 i think their are around  10k item records into the database. We don't have more then 5 version per item. The query we do is:

```cs
return rootItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(string.Format("descendant::*[@@{0}='{1}']", attributeName, attributeValue));
```

attributeName = TemplateName.

Do you have any ideas how I can optimize the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use Sitecore API for search. Use Sitecore Search:

```cs
public void Search(Item rootItem, string templateName)
{
    var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_" + Sitecore.Context.Database.Name + "_index");
    using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
    {
        var result = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.TemplateName == templateName && i.Paths.Contains(rootItem.ID));
        if (result != null)
        {
            Item resultItem = result.GetItem();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarekMusilak, thank you for the answer. I don't know why some times when I do the first query it  works and when I do your version is not working. I'm rebuilding the indexes maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Definitely, indexes must be rebuilt

Comment: @MareMusielak I've rebuild the indexes and change something in code all works fine. I do have a question does the above query works also for something like rootItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(string.Format("ancestor::*[@{0}='{1}']", fieldName, fieldValue)) ?

Comment: Yes. You can use any field. You need to create your own class inheriting from `SearchResultItem` and add another properties to it. Check https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer's_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-a4.pdf

Comment: I was thinking of using something like fast:/descendant:: is this correct?

Comment: There are some limitations for fast query. You would need to check it. Standard query should work but it's not the fastest way

Comment: @Radu you can do something like this: context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.TemplateName == templateName && i["foo"].Equals("bar"));

meaning use the indexing notation i["fieldname"] to get to the fields. I.Paths will contains the ids of the item's parents

Comment: @RubenVerschueren yes i've something like that and it worked. Thank you!